# Writing an interpreter for a language with breaks

Tags: scheme, racket, interpreter, continuations, continuation-passing

I'm trying to write an interpreter for a simple programming language in Scheme. Right now, I'm writing a procedure to handle while-loops with break statements. To approach this problem, I'm using call/cc.

When the language is parsed, it looks like this:

```
var x = 0;
while (x < 10) {
  x = x - 1;
  break;
  x = x + 100;
}
return x;
```

turns into

```
((var x 0) (while (< x 10) (begin (= x (- x 1)) (break) (= x (+ x 100)))) (return x))
```

My approach to interpreting these statements is as follows:

```
(define while_break
  (lambda (cond body state)
    (call/cc
     (lambda (break-cont)
       (letrec
           ((Mstate_loop (lambda (cond body state)
                         ; Need second loop
                         (if (eq? (M_Bool cond state) #t)
                             (call/cc
                              (lambda (second-break-cont)
                                (letrec
                                  ((Body_loop (lambda (body_line state)
                                                (cond
                                                  ((null? body_line) (second-break-cont state))
                                              ; Conditions to exit the loop
                                              ((eq? (first_line body_line) 'break) (second-break-cont state))
                                              ; If this is the last line, run it and break
                                              ((null? (rest_of_lines body_line)) (second-break-cont (M_State body_line state)))
                                              ; Otherwise, run the next line
                                              (else (Body_loop (rest_of_lines body_line) (M_State (first_line body_line) state)))))))
                            (Body_loop body state))))
                          (break-cont state)
                          ))))
        (Mstate_loop cond body state))
     ))))


(define first_line car)
(define rest_of_lines cdr)
```

Where (M_State statement state) returns the current state updated to reflect statement (e.g. the state ((x) (2)) represents x = 2. (M_State '(var x 5) '((x) (2))) would return ((x) (5)).)

When I put this through the debugger, the line 
    ((null? body_line) (second-break-cont state))
always calls upon second-break-cont, even though body_line is not null. I've spent a lot of time debugging this, but can't seem to find the error. Any help in spotting my mistake would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without looking too much at your code, I will advise that you may want to use delimited continuations to scope the extent of your `break` implementation.

Comment: @AlexisKing Or, if the whole loop is being interpreted in the same function, it's possible to avoid `call/cc` entirely by making the (Scheme-level) loop take an extra parameter, that could take on values `'break` and `'continue` (for example). The test condition is then evaluated only if the mode is `'continue`.

Comment: reformat your code with `(define (func args...) ...` and named lets `(let name ((a a) (b b) (c c)) ...)`, and it'll get much more compact and readable. Also, for me, it helps writing `(call/cc (lambda (exit) ...` on one line, incrementing the next lines under the `call/cc`, not under `lambda`; but that's a bit unorthodox.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't studied your code in detail, but I noticed one thing. You had a parameter named `cond` for both your main function as well as the outer loop. This will shadow the built-in `cond` macro, which you tried to use in your inner loop.

In fact, that alone would explain why your `(second-break-cont state)` is always called. The `cond` expression is no longer a macro invocation, but a normal function call, so all expressions inside are evaluated.

You should call your parameter something other than `cond`.